# How to call a shell script from UI with out App server and web server?

Tags: java, linux, user-interface, marklogic

I have a shell script and argument as a date. I'm looking for some help in design, where I will have to create a UI and pass the date, so that it will call the shell script with an argument (it should open unix terminal and call the shell script with username and password). The whole shell script runs on LINUX server. I would preferably be on MarkLogic/Java/Unix and Scala. I should not use  web server in my application.

Can someone please suggest how to call the shell script from Java application with out using an Appserver/Webserver.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [calling shell script from Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34204044/calling-shell-script-from-java)

Comment: @nhouser9 : I need user interface too ,to update the date . How ever i don't have app server . I am looking for feasible solution  where i have UI with out App server/Web server and it will take to the Unix shell scripting . but i don't have the design  and architecture to implement

Answer (score 2):

I find your actual question  quite confusing and even more so after your clarification to nhouser9.

What I interpret is :
1) You need a user interface (but not a terminal?)
- Your simple need may be addressed with the tried and true old timer Java Abstract Windows Toolkit (AWT). Have a look at the wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Window_Toolkit
The sample code there compiles into a very simple **Hello World** GUI. (Java package info here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/package-summary.html)

2) You need to call a shell script from Java:
Then for this part of the question, have a look at nhouser9's original comment. That answer can be found here: [calling-shell-script-from-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34204044/calling-shell-script-from-java)  The heart of this is [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

Add 1 and 2 together and you can create a GUI to take a parameter and then execute a shell script.